# run two docker containers in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I know you can upload a docker container to an AWS lambda function. Is there a way to map two docker containers to the same lambda function? So that one executes after the other. This would allow some local communication through the temp disk.

Comment: No you can't do this. Use ECS for such a use-case.

Comment: Well technically you can just set up a docker environment on the lambda function, pull the docker containers, and then execute docker run. I am trying to see if there's a better way. Curious about ECS: how do you define container pipelines in ECS? AWS Step Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately a Lambda function may only be tied to a single Docker image.

There's a couple ways you could go about achieving this desired functionality:

If you don't *need* two separate lambda functions, you can break your project into distinct files while still having everything wrapped in a single container. It might look something like this:

```
project_name
|
--- Dockerfile
|
--- src
    |
    --- lambda_function.py
    |
    --- file1.py
    |
    --- file2.py
```

where `lambda_function.py` contains your handler which calls methods from `file1.py` and `file2.py`.

If you do need two distinct Lambdas, you have a couple options. First I would suggest setting up an API Gateway in between lambda 1 and lambda 2. This way, lambda 1 can make a curl request against the API, which will call the second lambda on your behalf.

Another option would be Step Functions. It provides a nice UI to set up how your Lambdas will interact with each other. The downside of Step Functions is that it quickly becomes unmanageable as you add more lambdas to the mix.

Comment: Why do you say that Step Functions become unmanageable as you add more lambdas to the mix? I thought their stated purpose is to manage a lot of lambdas.

Comment: In theory that's right, Step Functions is for managing a lot of Lambdas. But in practice it gets hairy really fast. For starters each Lambda has its own deployment pipeline/repository that you have to maintain. Additionally the whole Step Functions process gets hard to debug as you add more Lambdas.

I haven't personally used it, but my teammates have made their gripes with Step Functions abundantly clear. They recommend looking into Managed Airflow as another alternative.